# Is there any way to enforce parameter order?

Tags: php

I have the following function...

```
function myFunction($arg1 = '', arg2 = '') {
    return 'My args: ' . $arg1 . ' & ' . $arg2;
}
```

... which I call with the data retrieved from GET in...

```
$arg1 = retrieve($_GET, 'arg1'); // custom function
$arg2 = retrieve($_GET, 'arg2'); // retrieves array value or empty string

$result = myFunction($arg1, $arg2);
```

... but ...

```
echo ($result === 'My args: ' . $arg1 . ' & ' . $arg2); // Why is this false?
```

Given that `arg1` results in an empty string, but `arg2` does not, why is the value of `arg2` considered `arg1` once it's been passed on to the function?

I'm a newbie to PHP, I'm most used to Java, and the introduction of optional parameters plus a mix of paradigms, etc confuses me.

**TLDR;** *Why is `arg1` not empty when called as `myFunction('', $arg2);`*

EDIT: Posted code is made-up; actual code can be found here -> http://pastie.org/8623944#7

EDIT2: Testing code again, it was a typo on my part; I was reassigning $arg1 the value of $arg2 BEFORE passing it to the function. My bad.

Comment: can you show your output?

Comment: Your assumptions are totally wrong, no matter what value you pass for `$arg1`, it **will be passed**. `$arg2` will not "slide over" into `$arg1`. Also, don't post "made up" code and then link to your real code, just **post your real code**.

Comment: `arg2` is never considered to be `arg1`. See here for some examples: http://3v4l.org/AXvXb. You have a completely different issue in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Your function does not return the string, but echoes it, so the `===` will never be true

try

```
function myFunction($arg1 = '', arg2 = '') {
   return 'My args: ' . $arg1 . ' & ' . $arg2;
}
```

Comment: I made up the code as I wrote the post, you can consider that a typo. I will update the OP with the actual code.

Comment: next time post your actual code please, now it is just guessing that your problem is also in this code..... Have you actually tested that your problem is in the current code?

Comment: Yes, I have, with `echo`s both out and inside the function. The portrayed problem is persistant.

Comment: it could be anywhere from your retrieve function in your sample code to the `searchPeople` in your real code.

Comment: I found the issue, finally. I was reassinging $arg1 instead of assigning $arg2. Totally my fault for copy-pasing code.